# wildfly jboss standalone configuration for microsoft azureload balancer

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x, azure-load-balancer

Can anyone tell me what configuration is needed in `standalone.xml` to integrate *Wilfly Jboss 7* with *Microsoft Azure Load balancer*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a web farm for the servers API in azure and route the traffic at round robin fashion to each server.

You may see the access log with the api URL.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback.